# How to parse an array in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I created a stored procedure that looks like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [EXP_RfPickAfter] (
    @SESSIONVALUE xml,
    @WorkDSArray nvarchar(max),
    @UserSignonDS nvarchar(max),
    @Direction nvarchar(max),
    @ImmediateCount nvarchar(max),
    @CCWorkUnit nvarchar(max),
    @PartialPick nvarchar(max),
    @RETURNVALUE nvarchar(max) output
       )
      AS 
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
@workDSArray has this long string in it 

924WORK0924841SEQUENCE8410841842EQUIPMENT_LOC842842843PARENT_LOGISTICS_    
UNIT843843844REFERENCE_TYPE844Order844845INVENTORY_AT_
PD845845846FROMVER846None846847INTERNAL_NUM8476851842847848START_
DATE_TIME848848849INCHKDIG849849850TOTAL_VOLUME8500850851
TO_LOC851SHIP-1851852INTERNAL_NUM_TYPE852Shipment852853
WEIGHT_UM853LB853854COMPANY854SHOS854855QUANTITY_UM855CS855856OUTGOING_
PD_LOC856856857WORK_TYPE857LPNPick857858END_DATE_TIME858858859
ACTUALFROMWHS859L455859860LOT860860861WORK_ZONE1861861862
TOCONTAINERID8621862863INVER863863864TRACK_CONTAINERS864N864865
TO_LOC_INV_ATTRIBUTES_ID865865866CYCLE_COUNT866866867
LAUNCH_NUM86716949391867868ACTUALTOLOC868-jisavm3868869
FROM_CHECK_DIG869869870FROM_WHS870L455870871
WORK_GROUP871Picking871872INTERNAL_LINE_NUM187232612518872873
VOLUME_UM873873874ACTUALFROMLOC874NF-1-F-28-1874875
INTERNAL_REQ_NUM87520774185875876TO_WHS876L455876877
INTERNAL_LINE_NUM87732612518877878TREE_UNIT87826385537878879
INWRKZONE879879880PUTLOC880SHIP-1880881CONTAINER_ID88116489660881882
INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM88226385537882883FROMTRKCONT883Y883884
PARENT_CONTAINER_NUM8840884885CONVERTED_QTY_UM885CS885886
ACTUALTOWHS886L455886887OUTWRKZONE887887888
VERIFICATION_METH888None888889USER_DEF4889 L455-RS 2889890
REFERENCE_ID890XKJNNLJN890891LOGISTICS_UNIT89116489660891892
MESSAGE_ID892892893PICKLOC893NF-1-F-28-1893894
CURRENTLOC894F894895TREE_UNIT_ID89516489660895897
TOCONTAINERID089716489660897898TOTAL_WEIGHT8981898899
TOTAL_VALUE8990899900TO_CHECK_DIG900900901OUTCHECKDIG901901902
TO_QTY9020902903INTRKCONT903903904FROM_LOC_INV_ATTRIBUTES_ID904904905
INTERNAL_INSTRUCTION_NUM90520699485905906ITEM_DESC906MSF21D4MDE -       
Refrigerator906907ITEM907SHOS-STOCK907908
COMPLETEDBYUSER908jisavm3908909
TRANSPORT_CONT_ID90916489660909910OUTTRKCONT910910911ACCOUNT911
Store #9449911912INCOMING_PD_LOC912912913INVENTORY_TRACKING913Y913914
LOCATION_CLASS914Shipping Dock914915FROM_QTY9151915916OUTVERMETH916916917
CONVERTED_QTY9171917918QUANTITY9181918919
PARENT_INSTR91920699484919920
FROM_LOC920NF-1-F-28-1920921WORK_ZONE921W- 
Returns921922WORK_UNIT92216489660922923QTY
CONFIRMED9231923924925WORK9251925
```

I am trying to parse containerID and its value from this string and use it in a select statement in my stored procedure, but I am unsure how to parse only the containerID.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: Provide your select statment

Comment: I sincerely hope this is part of a process to get the data into the database, and the DB itself isn't relying on storing every single data point in NVARCHAR(MAX). But the answer is, use SUBSTRING(). The exact logic depends on the structure of the data inside the string.

Comment: what I would do is use the container ID to do another select to get the data I want to insert into the database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @hogan stated in his comment, you can use string operators for extraction with some while and if-else statements

-- I am editing my answer.

To retrieve the container ID you use a store procedure like this:

```
create proc getid (@string varchar(max)) as

declare @containerIdIndex int = (select charindex('CONTAINER_ID',@string))

declare @internalContainerIndex int = (select(Charindex('INTERNAL_CONTAINER', @string)))

declare @range int = @internalContainerindex-@containerIdindex+12
declare @start int = @containerIdIndex+12  --12 is to pass the 'Container_ID'

declare @containerId varchar(max)
set @containerId = substring(@string,@start,@range)
print @containerId
```

Comment: So if I did something like DECLARE @Document varchar(max)

Comment: So if I did something like DECLARE atContainerID varchar(64) select CHARINDEX('ContainerID', atContainerID); DECLARE atID varchar(8) SELECT CHARINDEX('atCONTAINERID', 16) wherever the actual ID starts?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11063880)

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I am sorry, I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @JoshuaDeshazer Yes, I would use DECLARE atContainerID varchar(64)= select CHARINDEX('ContainerID', atContainerID); and one for the Track_Containers to get its index too. Then the range to extract the id. I think you can apply this logic to get everything

Comment: Thank you for your comments they are helping. I did not quite understand how to parse out the one and only ID i needed

Comment: @JoshuaDeshazer I have changed my answer. I hope this code helps

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get the right ID I had to trigger off of something else. This is not ideal because I don't know if the string will change. If anybody knows a better way please post and thank you @ymuribbi you helped me out a ton. I edited this to show my full solution just in case someone else runs into this issue.

```
 DECLARE @WorkDSArray nvarchar(max);

    SET @WorkDSArray= '924WORK0924841SEQUENCE8410841842EQUIPMENT_LOC842842843PARENT_LOGISTICS_UNIT843843844REFERENCE_TYPE844Order844845INVENTORY_AT_PD845845846FROMVER846None846847INTERNAL_NUM8476851842847848START_DATE_TIME848848849INCHKDIG849849850TOTAL_VOLUME8500850851TO_LOC851SHIP-1851852INTERNAL_NUM_TYPE852Shipment852853WEIGHT_UM853LB853854COMPANY854SHOS854855QUANTITY_UM855CS855856OUTGOING_PD_LOC856856857WORK_TYPE857LPN Pick857858END_DATE_TIME858858859ACTUALFROMWHS859L455859860LOT860860861WORK_ZONE1861861862TOCONTAINERID8621862863INVER863863864TRACK_CONTAINERS864N864865TO_LOC_INV_ATTRIBUTES_ID865865866CYCLE_COUNT866866867LAUNCH_NUM86716949391867868ACTUALTOLOC868-jisavm3868869FROM_CHECK_DIG869869870FROM_WHS870L455870871WORK_GROUP871Picking871872INTERNAL_LINE_NUM187232612518872873VOLUME_UM873873874ACTUALFROMLOC874NF-1-F-28-1874875INTERNAL_REQ_NUM87520774185875876TO_WHS876L455876877INTERNAL_LINE_NUM87732612518877878TREE_UNIT87826385537878879INWRKZONE879879880PUTLOC880SHIP-1880881CONTAINER_ID88116489660881882INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM88226385537882883FROMTRKCONT883Y883884PARENT_CONTAINER_NUM8840884885CONVERTED_QTY_UM885CS885886ACTUALTOWHS886L455886887OUTWRKZONE887887888VERIFICATION_METH888None888889USER_DEF4889 L455-RS 2889890REFERENCE_ID890XKJNNLJN890891LOGISTICS_UNIT89116489660891892MESSAGE_ID892892893PICKLOC893NF-1-F-28-1893894CURRENTLOC894F894895TREE_UNIT_ID89516489660895897TOCONTAINERID089716489660897898TOTAL_WEIGHT8981898899TOTAL_VALUE8990899900TO_CHECK_DIG900900901OUTCHECKDIG901901902TO_QTY9020902903INTRKCONT903903904FROM_LOC_INV_ATTRIBUTES_ID904904905INTERNAL_INSTRUCTION_NUM90520699485905906ITEM_DESC906MSF21D4MDE - Refrigerator906907ITEM907SHOS-STOCK907908COMPLETEDBYUSER908jisavm3908909TRANSPORT_CONT_ID90916489660909910OUTTRKCONT910910911ACCOUNT911Store #9449911912INCOMING_PD_LOC912912913INVENTORY_TRACKING913Y913914LOCATION_CLASS914Shipping Dock914915FROM_QTY9151915916OUTVERMETH916916917CONVERTED_QTY9171917918QUANTITY9181918919PARENT_INSTR91920699484919920FROM_LOC920NF-1-F-28-1920921WORK_ZONE921W-Returns921922WORK_UNIT92216489660922923QTYCONFIRMED9231923924925WORK9251925'
    DECLARE @ContainerID integer;

    SET @ContainerID = CHARINDEX('TREE_UNIT_ID', @WorkDSArray); 

    DECLARE @ID nvarchar(max); 

    SET @ID = SUBSTRING(@WorkDSArray, @ContainerID,300)

    SELECT @ID;

    DECLARE @ActualContainerID nvarchar(max); 

    SET @ActualContainerID = SUBSTRING(@ID, 54, 9)

    SET @ActualContainerID = REPLACE(@ActualContainerID, CHAR(31), '')

    DECLARE @User integer

    DECLARE @UserID nvarchar(max) 

    SET @User = CHARINDEX('COMPLETEDBYUSER', @WorkDSArray);

    SET @UserID = SUBSTRING(@WorkDSArray, @User,27)

    DECLARE @ActualUserID nvarchar(max); 

    SET @ActualUserID = SUBSTRING(@UserID, 20, 8)

    SET @ActualUserID = REPLACE(@ActualUserID, CHAR(31), '')

    DECLARE @Shipment nvarchar(max)
    SET @Shipment = (SELECT CASE WHEN SH.COMPANY = 'SHOS' THEN '' ELSE SH.SHIPMENT_ID + '|' + 
SH."ROUTE" + '|' + 
SH."STOP" + '|' + 
SH.COMPANY + '|' + 
LEFT(SH.CUSTOMER_NAME,25) + '|' +
LEFT(SH.SHIP_TO_ADDRESS1,25) + '|' +
CASE WHEN SH.SHIP_TO_ADDRESS2 <> '' THEN SH.SHIP_TO_ADDRESS2 + '|' 
ELSE '' END +
LEFT(SH.SHIP_TO_CITY,25) + '|' +
LEFT(SH.SHIP_TO_STATE,25) + '|' +
LEFT(SH.SHIP_TO_POSTAL_CODE,25) END
FROM SHIPMENT_HEADER SH
JOIN SHIPPING_CONTAINER SC
ON SC.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = SH.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM
WHERE SC.CONTAINER_ID = @ActualContainerID)

     DECLARE @ShipmentID nvarchar(max)

   SET @ShipmentID = SUBSTRING(@Shipment,0,9)



      --select top 1  device_name from dbo.DOCUMENT_ROUTING where document_type = 'HJBT_REC' and user_name = @user

     INSERT INTO [jbh].[PRT_REQ_WRK] 
     ([REQ_REF_TYP], [REQ_REF_I], [PRT_DVC_NM], [REQ_TMPL_NM], [REQ_VAL], [PRT_STT], [PRT_PRS_TYP], [PRT_Q], [CRT_S], [CRT_UID], [CRT_PGM_C], [LST_UPD_S], [LST_UPD_UID], [LST_UPD_PGM_C]) 
     VALUES (
     @ShipmentID, --[REQ_REF_TYP]
     '123abc', --[REQ_REF_I]
     'LB01885', --[PRT_DVC_NM]
     'HJBT_Shipping_Label.lbl', --[REQ_TMPL_NM]
     @Shipment, --[REQ_VAL]
     0, --[PRT_STT]
     'LABEL', --[PRT_PRS_TYP]
      1, --[PRT_Q]
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, --[CRT_S]
      @ActualUserID, --[CRT_UID]
     'WMSPrintService', --[CRT_PGM_C]
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, --[LST_UPD_S]
     'JISAVM3', --[LST_UPD_UID]
     'WMSPrintService') --[LST_UPD_PGM_C]
```

Comment: now i am trying to do my select based off of this SELECT * 
FROM SHIPPING_CONTAINER
WHERE CONTAINER_ID = @ActualContainerID and I am not pulling in a record, but I do pull in a record if I hard code the containerID

Comment: I fixed it it was because a unit separator was in my string I fixed that with SET @ActualContainerID = REPLACE(@ActualContainerID, CHAR(31), '')